# How can I change initial login page for phpMyAdmin4?

Tags: phpmyadmin

**How can I change initial login page for phpMyAdmin4?** I want to add some text to 'Welcome to phpMyAdmin'. Have been looking for file to change but can't find it. Thanks.

Comment: `index.php` comes to mind but I'll be right back after these messages. Please list what you've tried in the meantime.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the .php file responsible for logging the user in?  I would assume its login.php ( logical choice ) but this appears like it will generate programming based answers.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin 4.2.11 it looks like you can find `Username: <inputbox>` in `libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php` and on line #125 is the Welcome message you need.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you MonkeyZeus, you're right on the money.

Comment: Try using FTP and/or downloading the files from source, and using an IDE to find in all files some of the content on the page you want to change, or by using the file in comments above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer  on AuthenticationCookie.class.php  file editing.
Following is an example of adding extra string around "phpMyAdmin" text.

```
<snipped>
       echo sprintf(
            __('Welcome to %s'),
            '<bdo dir="ltr" lang="en">Mysql DB management via phpMyAdmin GUI </bdo>'
       );
        echo "</h1>";
<snipped>
```